# What does gpu-manager do?

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to understand what gpu-manager actually does. My searching has only found to disable it in grub and comment out gpu-manager.conf due to it overwriting xorg.conf. 
I am running 14.04 Xubuntu, 3 Nvidia 970's and their binary driver. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gpu-manager is software that creates a xorg.conf for you.

It is a bug in gpu-manager: it recreates xorg.org on each boot. Let Ubuntu do its thing and disable `gpu-manager` as you already mentioned.

Have a look at `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` for any messages. If you add yourself to the bug below (that claims to be fixed but comments at the bottom disagree...) you need that log.

And this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489) has the [work-around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489/comments/5) you describe (by Nash Kaminski on 2014-04-22):

> `gpu-manager` is responsible for overwriting your X config file. Commenting out the "start on" lines at the top of gpu-manager's upstart script located at `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf` will temporarily disable `gpu-manager` and prevent `xorg.conf` from being changed.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it can be useful if you're frequently changing the GPU configuration, for instance if you're using a laptop with an external GPU.