# Error after downloading and installing Bumblebee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

So, i've changed the .conf file adding my NVIDIA driver (nvidia-440) and when i try to optirun it just doesn't work, so i need some help with that, i've an Intel I7-7500U (HD 620) and a Geforce 920mx, i need help finding log files to solve this problem, thank.

`optirun glxgears -info`

```
[ 1036.915525] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1036.915603] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

When i try to see bumblebee.socket for any config or help:

`sudo gedit /var/run/bumblebee.socket`

No text or archives in this file, and it isn't at the path as well.
There was some error installing Bumble bee, an Error 404 in the repository. Thanks for the help.

bumblebee.conf file:

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
# Xorg binary to run
XorgBinary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-440
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-440:/usr/lib32/nvidia-440:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-440/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
# If set to true, will always unload the kernel module(s) even with
# PMMethod=none - useful for newer Optimus models on which the kernel power
# management works out of the box to power the card on/off without bbswitch.
AlwaysUnloadKernelDriver=false

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Found another log, clarifying what happened.

```
ago 20 12:52:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 32.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: Stopped Bumblebee C Daemon.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[6828]: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'hostpci0:'
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[6828]: [ 1964.180935] [WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[6828]: [ 1964.181229] [ERROR]Module 'nvidia-440' is not found.
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ago 20 12:53:21 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Switched nvidia-440 for nvidia, restarted the service and now it is getting me another error:

```
bumblebeed.service - Bumblebee C Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-08-20 12:58:43 -03; 1min 44s ago
   Main PID: 7048 (bumblebeed)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9373)
     Memory: 624.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bumblebeed.service
             └─7048 /usr/sbin/bumblebeed

ago 20 12:58:43 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
ago 20 12:58:43 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[7048]: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'hostpci0:'
ago 20 12:58:43 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[7048]: [ 2286.122440] [WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
ago 20 12:58:43 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[7048]: [ 2286.122639] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
ago 20 12:58:45 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[7048]: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module: could not find module by name='off'
ago 20 12:58:45 joaopedro-300E5M-300E5L bumblebeed[7048]: [ 2288.249844] [ERROR]Could not load GPU driver
```

Fixed it with help of this post:
[bumblebee doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029169/bumblebee-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04)